# How do i use the grep command in a different directory with out using cd

Tags: command-line, programming, dash-shell

I want to search for a pattern in some files  but without using cd to enter the directory they are saved in. How can i do that?

Comment: `grep pattern /absolute/path/of/the/file` or `grep pattern relative/path/of/the/file`.

Comment: I tried it but it says thats the path im using is a directory

Comment: Try `ls -l /absolute/path/of/the/directory | grep pattern`

Comment: @ΧρύσαΠιπερίδου Do you want find the pattern in the file content or filename? If you want to find in all files of a directory, you can use `grep -r /path/to/directory`.

Comment: Inside the content. Thank you that worked!

Comment: @Kulfy Can you post an answer that Χρύσα Πιπερίδου can accept?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done. :)

Comment: @Kulfy Upvoted and I'll delete my comments later... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can provide absolute path or relative path of the file. Absolute path generally starts with the root of the file system hierarchy, i.e., `/` and relative path starts with the name of sub-directory in the current directory that contains the files.

Absolute paths are ideal when you're currently in different hierarchy. For example, when I'm currently in `$HOME/Desktop` and I want to access files from `c` in `/mnt`, then I'll use absolute path, i.e., `/mnt/c`. On the other hand, relative paths are ideal if the folder you want to search in is in the current directory or the subdirectory of the current directory. When you use `file.txt`, you're actually using relative path.

If a pattern is to be searched in all the files in some directory, `*` can be used in shells which supports [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) or alternatively, `-r` option of [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html) can be used which would search in all files in the directory recursively. For example:

```
grep -r pattern /absolute/path/of/the/file
```

Or if the symlinks are to be ignored, `-R` can be used

```
grep -R pattern /absolute/path/of/the/file
```